# visual studio code python terminal three dots

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

a = [1,2,3,4]
print(a)

when i run this code in visual studio code editor, output doesn't show up automatically.

the terminal window shows the command and doesn't print unless I press enter

`In [14]: a = [1,2,3,4]`

`...: print(a)`  
 `...:`

Comment: Python is whitespace important, press enter after `a = [1,2,3,4]`, what Python method do you use, read the VSC Python docs and choose one method, do not mix methods

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.